# debugging infrasturcture for RAP application

Tags: eclipse

I am developing a RAP application.

In this application i fetched some end user specific java class and if she/he wants to debug those java file in browser itself.

What are the infrastructure available to debug?

Is JPDA available for RAP?

```
             ***********************************
```

I have spent whole fortnight to get some solution for this problem.

I dint find any solution. Sad

I am developing a RAP application in which i am getting some java files(user defined java files ,not java code of RAP) in web browser.I want to debug those java files over the web browser .

Is there any way to get simple debug view at client side(where i am running RAP) in browser?

Is there any to attach VM at server side(where i am calling services to populate data over the web browser) ?

Please help me

I would appreciate any feedback regarding this

Smile

P.S. it is different than debugging java script (I don't need to debug java script),its pure java code debugging.

Answer (score 1):

For me, remote debugging a RAP application in Tomcat from Eclipse worked after following a routine similar to that described in the [answer from coz](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383649/2134990) with a few exceptions. Restarting the application didn't help me but what was really important was to build with debug info and then clear (!) Tomcat's **work directory** from previous deployments. OSGi makes use of it.
So in a nutshell my steps were:

1. Build war with debug info. As I use maven so I post here the config for the compiler plugin:

   ```
   <plugin>
       <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
       <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>2.4</version>
       <configuration>
           <source>1.7</source>
           <target>1.7</target>
           <debug>true</debug>
           <debuglevel>lines,vars,source</debuglevel> 
       </configuration>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. Clear previous deployments (check and clear **webapps** and **work** directories)
3. Start Tomcat in debug mode: `catalina jpda start` and deploy the new build
4. Start a Remote debug launch configuration from Eclipse

That's all.
Steps 3 and 4 are trivial and should work with the default settings. Again, the most relevant steps here are 1 and 2.

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

Here (http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/Developing) is a page showing "how do remotely debug Tomcat using Eclipse".
For Eclipse RAP here are some steps I use:

1. Build the war using ant and compiling adding debug information. Use: debug="true" debuglevel="lines,vars,source" in the javac target
2. Start tomcat using jpda; tomcat will automatically deploy your war
3. Stop the webapp in the tomcat manager
4. Start remote debugging configuration in Eclipse (it should not display any errors; building the war without debug info is the most common error)
5. Start the application in tomcat manager
6. The breakpoints in Eclipse should be hit.